# Get property value from $resource object AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I am beginner in AngularJS but i must modify little module for my project.
Here is my service factory:

```
services.factory('NewsService', function($resource) {

    var result = $resource('http://localhost:8090/boiler/1');
    return result;
});
```

Here i use it:

```
function IndexController($scope, NewsService) {

    var result = NewsService.get()

    $scope.xxx= result.day;
    $scope.www = result;
```

I don't understand why I can send to $scope variable `result` and use it in html as `{{www.day}}` but i can't send to $scope property of variable `result.day` and use it as `{{xxx}}`

This is my Json response from server

```
{
  "day" : "2016-10-06",
  "amountOfEnergy" : 40,
  "cost" : 120,
  "content" : [ ],
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8090/boiler/1"
  }, {
    "rel" : "bathroom",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8090/boiler/1"
  } ]
}
```

Somebody can explain me it?

Comment: Can you please tell us what error you get or how `$scope` looks like ?

Comment: getting any eorrs?when i checked with both cases i am able to see the day....

Comment: I don't check any errors in browser console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$resource` return promise so use `$promise.then` in controller

```
function IndexController($scope, NewsService) {
    NewsService.get()
       .$promise
       .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            var result = response;
            $scope.xxx= result.day;
            $scope.www = result;
       });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this will be better (from [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) doc):

```
function IndexController($scope, NewsService) {
    $scope.result = {};

    NewsService.get({}, function (data) {
      $scope.result = data;
    });
};
```

and in template {{ result.day }}

Comment: But how to get normal Java Script object from $resource object, because i need to have access to property of it for example "day" in JS code .

Comment: NewsService.get - async function and it need callback, where you can operrate with result.
$scope.result - is the normal object and also it can be use into template directly. In callback you can do anything, like `console.log($scope.result.day)`